# Angular ng build --prod errors: Type not assignable and Property does not exist

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

`ng serve` works fine, but `ng build --prod` throws a few errors:

1) "*Type 'boolean | ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.*"

It refers to this snippet:

```
 <clr-wizard-page #pageGeneral [clrWizardPageNextDisabled]="!datainputForm.get('company').valid || !datainputForm.get('email').valid">
```

2) 
"*Property 'open' does not exist on type 'XYZComponent'*"
I have used the original code from VMware's Clarity UI, but must have missed to declare something, because the modals on the page cause the same error:

"*Property 'configIdModalOpen' does not exist on type 'XYZComponent'*"

`<clr-wizard #wizard [(clrWizardOpen)]="open" [clrWizardClosable]="false">`

`<clr-modal #configIdModal [(clrModalOpen)]="configIdModalOpen">`

Comment: Property 'open' does not exist on type 'XYZComponent meaning define open as public. If it is private it won't work in prod build. It will throw error

Comment: Please update your component code

Comment: Hi Pratap, how/where am I going to define it? Thanks!

Comment: in your component file. Please update component code

Comment: That worked! Thanks! You don't happen to have an idea why the "Type 'boolean | ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'ValidationErrors' is not assignable to type 'boolean'." error occurs?

Comment: Nevermind! Had an error and fixed it

Answer (score 1):

@Pratap A.K was correct: "Property 'open' does not exist on type 'XYZComponent meaning define open as public. If it is private it won't work in prod build. It will throw error"

The remaining issues were user errors/typos.